# What does "Scalars leaked: 1" mean?

Tags: perl

I just got the warning "Scalars leaked: 1" nine times.

I'm guessing it came from a threaded upload program that uses 9 threads with modules threads, threads::shared and Thread::Queue.  This is on WinXP, Active State 5.8.8.

Any idea what this means?  This program has been running a while with no such warnings, and I reran the program with the same (light) work that caused the warnings, but no warnings this time.

I'm not trying to start the threads at compile time, unless this is something that Thread::Queue does internally.  My first threaded call is after Getopt::Long processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From this website:](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=288022)

> Scalars leaked: 1
>   Yikes! What is that! "Scalars leaked: 1". Well, yes, that's one of the remaining problems/features/bugs of the Perl ithreads implementation. This particularly seems to happen when you start threads at compile time. From practical experience, I must say it seems to be pretty harmless. And compared to all of the other "leaking" of memory that happen because data-structures are copied, a single leaked scalar is presumably not a lot. And the error message is probably in error in this case anyway."

Comment: I saw that but noticed it was from 2003, and it didn't give much explanation about how to avoid the warning. That post is why I assume it came from the one threaded program I have.  I was hoping the SO's would know a bit more about it by now.

Comment: @BillRuppert I've looked for more on the subject but I couldn't find anything else... sorry.

Comment: Thanks, that was the only thing I could find as well.

Comment: @BillRuppert this may have been fixed in later versions of Perl.If you can I would see about upgrading to a newer version, since 5.8.x is no longer being updated.

Comment: @BradGilbert I'm working on an upgrade to 5.14, lots of work to get there though!  Eager to get it done, I don't even have // now.

Comment: @BillRuppert you may want to try to upgrade in steps. From 5.8 to 5.10 to 5.12 to 5.14, as there may have been features removed.